# How to delete a user template from Ignore File Generator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gitignore

[image: Ignore File Generator]

As you can see in the screenshot, I have a duplicate template. I got this window by right clicking on `.gitignore file -> Add template` in project tool window. I was looking to delete one but couldn't figure out how to do so. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for 'ignore files support' under settings.
File -> Settings... -> Ignore Files Support -> User templates

In there you will file your templates and can remove the one you want using the red minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to mgershen's answer, got a clue and finally I'm able to delete as well as edit and add the user template.

In Mac, the correct way is:

```
Preferences -> Version Control -> Ignore Files Support
```

In the user templates frame, select the template you want to remove and click on the `-` button.

[image: Ignore Files Support]